# Creating copies in inkscape using ctrl + left click + space bar?

Tags: inkscape

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/AgbsozDUyTs?t=376) and nick is able to create copies by pressing the <kbd>space bar</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click.  However, I cannot get this to work on Ubuntu 17.04 and Inkscape 0.92.  Thoughts?  Can I just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead or are copies and duplicates different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couldn't get this to work initially either, but it does. It's a little tricky.

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while left-clicking and dragging to rotate, but keep holding both <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+left click (don't release them), then hit the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to make a duplicate. Continue for the next rotation, but don't release the left click or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Yes, the <kbd>D</kbd> key does exactly the same if you release the mouse between rotations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am a Mac user. My solution was to hold shift at the same time. I.e hold 'shift'+'ctrl' and press space bar whilst moving the cursor around the object.

Comment: Please, can you explain better your solution also adding some images?

Comment: Hi Sorry, I realised my answer was not for this specific issue. It was for another one of Nick's tutorials. The edited answer was my solution for this specific problem.

Comment: Don't worry. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Select the object, left click and drag it where you want it. Continue to hold down the left mouse button and hit the space bar, a duplicate will be placed at that location.  Continue to hold down the left mouse button and drag the object to the next location, hit space bar again, repeat.